# How to set and access a variable in object literal notation?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set and later access a variable using object literal notation. I need to use this variable in subsequent code so I want to set it here just once.

When I run this code at jsFiddle, I get the error that HalfWidth is NaN.  How do I set and access this variable from here?

```
var $LIST = {
  FullWidth: 120,
  HalfWidth: this.FullWidth / 2,
  exit: function () {}
};

alert($LIST.FullWidth);
alert($LIST.HalfWidth);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7JcaQ/

Answer (score 3):

`this` have zero relevance to your situation - it is only defines context object for method call. Additionally, you cannot reference `$LIST` in its own definition, because it doesn't exits until definition ends.

Write:

```
var $LIST = {
  FullWidth: 120,
  exit: function () {}
};
$LIST.HalfWidth = $LIST.FullWidth / 2
```

(For the note, you're getting `NaN`, because outside of method call `this` is most often refers to global object, which naturally, most often don't have any numeric value in its `.FullWidth` property. Dividing this by 2 produces `NaN`.)